# Tag deletion possible?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-cleanup

If I make a new tag, then the question is deleted, does the tag disappear?

Or does the tag wonder around cyberspace?

Comment: Tags not associated with questions are pruned daily by the system. I am not entirely sure if the process includes tags that only appear in deleted questions or it's only about tags that have been removed from questions (i.e. orphan tags). I guess we can... experiment and see what happens?

Comment: @yannis It hangs around cyberspace. Symbols tag- https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/symbolism%2b

Comment: Ah, that's a very misleading page. It doesn't check if a tag exists or not, it just parses whatever is in the url and makes it look like a valid tag. For example, see: https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/Andrew%2bJohnson. To actually check if a tag exists, use the search in https://mythology.stackexchange.com/tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tag removal process is simple, as shown in an FAQ post on the Main Meta:
[How can we get rid of misspelled and unused (or "zombie") tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19753/236563)

Tags that have no associated open question are deleted by a script that runs overnight.